# why does chrome not align this text?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, valign

i have the following code

```
 <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/phone2.png"> <b>Phone Numbers:</b> (No orders via Phone at this time)<br />
```

and it looks fine in firefox:

[image]

but when i open it in chrome, it shows up like this:

[image]

does anyone know why chrome would raise the second part of this text ?

Comment: Without seeing your CSS it is rather hard to tell. And maybe consider creating a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating your example.

Comment: It works fine with just the provided html so it has to be something else which is missing from the question. http://jsfiddle.net/LhQja/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use valign attribute in your image tag, or
CSS vertical-align property applied to the image.

Comment: It's not the image that isn't aligning, it's the text in the `<b>` not aligning with the text outside of it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. In that case there must be a "vertical-align" property applied to some elements in your CSS code. Try to find them. That misalignment is due to a wrong "vertical-align" use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the result of different browser default styles applying to the various elements in your source. Try to set a `vertical-align` property for the `<b>` and `<img>` and test it again, for example:

```
b,img{
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

Comment: Right-click + "Inspect Element" is really useful for finding this stuff.  Chrome always shows what it's applying, even if it's a default value.  (I believe Firebug can as well, though not by default.)

Comment: Yes! You can apply CSS rules directly from the Chrome Inspector and find your answer in seconds.

Comment: @Isaac Lubow - i tried adding this but it didn't change anything

Comment: So you down-vote me? You didn't even post your CSS, dude. So far three responses have guessed it was a CSS problem. And I'm willing to bet we're right. Perhaps make sure both elements are `display:inline`, which would prevent `padding` from being applied. But without your code, we're just shooting in the dark.